# Joint probability density function of (X, X+Y)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I usually did those kind of exercises the other way (find marginal distribution when join is given) and got lost here:

Suppose X, Y are i.i.d. Uniform on (0,1). Find the pdf of random vector (X, X+Y).

$$
F_{(X,X+Y)}(t,k) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq t, X + Y \leq k) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq t, Y \leq k + t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq t)\mathbb{P}(Y \leq k + t) = F_{X}(t)F_{Y}(k+t)
$$

Should I take the partial derivatives of $t$ and $k$ to obtain it?

$$
\frac{\partial \left( F_{X}(t)F_{Y}(k+t) \right)}{\partial k} = F_{X}(t) g_Y(k+t)
$$

doing that the second time

$$
\frac{\partial \left(F_{X}(t) g_Y(k+t) \right)}{\partial t} = g_{X}(t) \frac{\partial g_Y(k+t)}{\partial t}
$$
Here I got stuck. It does not look like a very challenging example though...

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f \geq 0,$ using Fubini and independence, and the substitution $u=x+y$ ($x$ is fixed), we will have: $$E[f(X,X+Y)]=\int_{0}^1(\int_0^1f(x,x+y)dy)dx=\int_{0}^1(\int_{x}^{1+x}f(x,u)du)dx$$

It's uniform on $D=\left\{(x,u) \in [0,1] \times \mathbb{R}; x \leq u \leq x+1\right\}$ which means $f_{(X,X+Y)}(x,y)=1_D(x,y)$